# How to create number ID for each polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have some polygons and want to convert each polygon to a series of points. I use "feature vertices to points".
Here is the result.

The **Farm ID** field has SCAPD01-1 polygon and it has 190 points. I want SCAPD01-10 polygon, the number point start from 1 not 191.. And it should store point ID numbers in the **Point** field

[image]

Comment: Other field is "Farm ID". Polygon SCAPD01-1 has 190 points. I want polygon SCAPD01-10, the number point start from 1 not 191

Comment: I want to store the point number in "Point" field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you created a new field for this purpose called "Point".  You should be able to use the 'Calculate Field' to generate unique IDs sequentially for each group (according to a grouping field such as 'FarmID') by doing something like this:

- Right-click the column header for the Point field (or whatever your point ID field is called) and choose 'Field Calculator'
- In the Calculate Field's 'Code Block' parameter, enter:

```
idGroups = {}
def calculateIDs(groupID):
    global idGroups
    if groupID in idGroups:
        idGroups[groupID] += 1
    else:
        idGroups[groupID] = 1
    return idGroups[groupID]
```

- In the Calculate Field's 'Point' parameter (or whatever your point ID field is called), enter:

```
calculateIDs(!FarmID!)
```

(double click the 'FarmID' field to enter it correctly)

- Click the Calculate Field's 'Apply' button (or 'OK' button)

NB:  This is entirely untested.  I just made it up off the top of my head.

Comment: thanks. but when I try this python, there was a failure during processing.

Comment: It says:

ERROR 000539. Error running expression: calculate("SCAPD01-1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File"<expression>", line 1, in <module>
 File"<string>", line 4, in calculateID
KeyError: 'SCAPD01-1'

Comment: hii thanks a lot for the help.. it is very helpful